# C# MVC Submitting a list of values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, nested, grid

I want the user to enter a list of numbers in a grid, kind of like a bingo-card.

My model consists of a "size" (if 4, the grid will be 4 by 4), and a list of "field" object. A field consists of a X, Y and Value property.

```
public class MyGrid {
    public List<MyField> Fields { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public MyGrid() {
        Size = 9;
        Fields = new List<MyField>();
        for (int y = 0; y < Size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Size; x++) {
                Fields.Add(new MyField { X = x, Y = y });
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyField {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public MyField() {}
}
```

Now I want my view to render a grid of textboxes.

```
@model MyGrid
@using (Html.BeginForm("Initialize", "MyGrid")) {
    <table>
        @for (int y = 0; y < Model.Size; y++) {
            <tr>
                @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Size; x++) {
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Fields.Where(f => f.X == x && f.Y == y).First().Value)
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

So far, that works. But all textboxes have the ID "Value" ofcource.

Is there a way to create this grid so I can submit the whole grid into a single model?

Comment: The MVC binding to a list is somewhat annoying. You have to do something like: `PropertyName[0].ModelProp=value;PropertyName[1].ModelProp=value1` to get two models in a list. I did that with Ajax before, wasn't really pretty :/

Comment: I did something like that, using this: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this link, I found the answer:
https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

I've changed my view (for now):

Before:

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(s => s.Fields.Where(f => f.X == x && f.Y == y).First().Value)
</td>
```

After:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="fields.Index" value="field_@x@y">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Fields.Where(f => f.X == x && f.Y == y).First().Value, new { @Name = "fields[field_" + x + y + "].Value" } )
</td>
```

So, for each field there will be a "field.Index" hidden property.
And the textbox itself will have a Name corresponding with the value of the hidden field and the property attached to it.

This seems to work